# R Show duplicates in dataframe

Tags: r, sorting, duplicates

I am trying to "highlight" duplicates in my dataframe. I found various tutorials on dropping duplicates or creating a new dataset containing only duplicates. But since I expect something went wrong in earlier stages of my datawork, I would (for now) just like to see which observations appear to be duplicates in order to understand what went wrong. I would like R to create column c

```
a <- c("C","A","A","B","A","C","C")
b <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2)
c <- c(2,1,2,1,2,2,1)
df <-data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Comment: On what basis you want to detect duplicate? For column a, b or both?

Comment: I think your `c` value is wrong in row 5, as A - 2 combination appears twice.

Comment: @AntoniosK: yes you are right of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a <- c("C","A","A","B","A","C","C")
b <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2)
df <-data.frame(a,b)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(a,b) %>%    # for each combination of a and b
  mutate(c = n()) %>%  # count times they appear
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 7 x 3
#   a         b     c
#   <fct> <dbl> <int>
# 1 C         1     2
# 2 A         1     1
# 3 A         2     2
# 4 B         1     1
# 5 A         2     2
# 6 C         1     2
# 7 C         2     1
```